# How to perform operation on duplicate values in a table - SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table which has duplicate values:
[image: Input]

What I want to do is find rows with duplicate IDs `sum` values, if `sum` = 0 - delete(not select) those rows with duplicate IDs, if `sum` not equals 0 or IDs are not duplicate I need to keep them. So result should look like this:
[image: Output]

Any ideas how it can be done?
Thank you.

Comment: If you add `(4, 'abc', 300)`, how would that affect the result?

Comment: You say _delete those rows_, does that mean you really want to DELETE them from the table, or does it mean you don't want those rows in a SELECT's result set?

Comment: @jarlh editted my question, if sum not equals 0 keep them

Comment: @jarlh I am storing table in `temp_table` - so either one will work, deleting or not selecting them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a subquery that returns ID's having sum(value) = 0:

```
delete from tablename
where id in (select id from tablename
             group by id
             having sum(value) = 0)
```